# How to set HttpResponse StatusDescription in a content handler?

Tags: asp.net, iis, generic-handler

I am trying to set a custom HTTP status header in an HTTP response. E.g.:

```
400 Why do you want to do that
```

I am doing this by setting the `StatusDescription` of an `HttpResponse` in an `IHttpHandler`, in

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Foo" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class Foo : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        context.Response.StatusDescription = "Why do you want to do that";

            //Unnecessary; the string already contains this
        context.Response.Status = "400 Why do you want to do that";

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

But in the response headers from the server the *status line* doesn't contain what i told it to contain, and instead continues to contain the default StatusDescription:

```
400 Bad Request
```

[image]

[image]

How do change the `StatusDescription` of an `HttpResponse` header when in a generic *handler*?

## Bonus Chatter

There are three properties:

- **`int StatusCode`**: `400`
- **`String StatusDescription`**: `Bad Request`
- **`String Status`**: `400 Bad Request`

Setting the `StatusCode` will alter the `StatusDescription` and `Status`

```
                    StatuCode  StatusDescription  Status              
==================  =========  =================  ====================
initial             200        OK                 200 OK
StatusCode=400;
                    400        Bad Request        400 Bad Request
StatusDescription = "Too much want";
                    400        Too much want      400 Too much want
```

It also works the other way:

```
                    StatuCode  StatusDescription  Status              
==================  =========  =================  ====================
initial             200        OK                 200 OK
StatusDescription="Brilliant";
                    200        Brilliant          200 Brilliant
StatusCode=451;
                    451        Brilliant          451 Brilliant
```

and the other way

```
                    StatuCode  StatusDescription  Status              
==================  =========  =================  ====================
initial             200        OK                 200 OK
Status="451 Brilliant"
                    451        Brilliant          451 Brilliant
```

## Bonus Bonus Chatter

From [RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1):

> **6.1.1 Status Code and Reason Phrase**
>
> The individual values of the numeric status codes defined for HTTP/1.1, and an example set of corresponding Reason-Phrase's, are presented below. The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.